# Filling an array with arrays in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

A rather simple problem, and yet I dont seem to find any solution to it:

I am trying to use the differentiation of two arrays within an array and insert it as a new result into a new array... I hope the code clarifies this intention, even though it is not working, as python is telling me that it cannot combine a sequence with array calculation... How can I go around this problem? Thanks in advance!

```
MeteorNum = 5
#Coordinate Setup:

XPos = np.random.randint(0, 600, (MeteorNum,1))
YPos = np.random.randint(0, 800, (MeteorNum,1))

XYPos = np.hstack((XPos,YPos))
XYPos = np.vstack((XYPos, XYPos[0]))
print XYPos

#Distances:
r = np.zeros((MeteorNum,MeteorNum))

for i in range(0, MeteorNum):
    for x in range(0, MeteorNum):
        r[x,i] = (XYPos[x,:] - XYPos[i,:])
r = r*10**5
print r
```

and here the error I get:

```
runfile('C:/Users/Marco DS/Dropbox/1_TUDelft/4Q/AE1205 Python/python codes      2015/bonus assigments/week_5 Gravity simu.py', wdir='C:/Users/Marco   DS/Dropbox/1_TUDelft/4Q/AE1205 Python/python codes 2015/bonus assigments')
[[249 660]
 [256 605]
 [119 423]
 [422 398]
 [480 504]
 [249 660]]
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-57-4cd9cc29ece0>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Marco DS/Dropbox/1_TUDelft/4Q/AE1205 Python/python     codes 2015/bonus assigments/week_5 Gravity simu.py', wdir='C:/Users/Marco     DS/Dropbox/1_TUDelft/4Q/AE1205 Python/python codes 2015/bonus assigments')

  File "C:\Users\Marco DS\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 682, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

File "C:\Users\Marco DS\Anaconda\lib\site-    packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 71, in execfile
exec(compile(scripttext, filename, 'exec'), glob, loc)

  File "C:/Users/Marco DS/Dropbox/1_TUDelft/4Q/AE1205 Python/python codes 2015/bonus assigments/week_5 Gravity simu.py", line 37, in <module>
r[x,i] = (XYPos[x,:] - XYPos[i,:])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: please show all the errors ...

Comment: Please show the entire error message (traceback), it should have a line number, the line it is stuck on, the function name, the module name, ...

Comment: What do you mean with differentiation? Just computing the difference of the left and the right column?

Comment: Is it intentional that you store the `np.hstack` and `np.vstack` in the same variable?

Comment: P.R. the vstack is in order to copy and add the first element to the last element of the array. That way, when I use the for loops,  I can make sure all values are included.

Comment: Where is the Value Error?  Which line?  Or do you expect us to run the code and find out for ourselves?

Comment: here, I hope this is better now...

Answer (score 2):

try to add `dtype=` in the container array:

```py
MeteorNum = 5
#Coordinate Setup:

XPos = nprand.randint(0, 600, (MeteorNum,1))
YPos = nprand.randint(0, 800, (MeteorNum,1))

XYPos = np.hstack((XPos,YPos))
XYPos = np.vstack((XYPos, XYPos[0]))
print XYPos

#Distances:
r = np.zeros((MeteorNum,MeteorNum),dtype=np.ndarray)

for i in range(0, MeteorNum):
    for x in range(0, MeteorNum):
        r[x,i] = (XYPos[x,:] - XYPos[i,:])
r = r*10**5
print r
```

**EDIT**

> The dtype argument indicate the desired data-type for the array, e.g.,
>   numpy.int8. Default is numpy.float64.

Comment: Yes! That worked for me! It now gives me a huge array, which is what I needed. However, all elements now also say "array" and then what is in it, but oh well. it does the job... What though does the dtype do?

Comment: I edited my answer to define the dtype argument role

Comment: @user3604362 you can accept the answer if it was helpful for you

Answer (score 1):

To remove errors, I think you need an extra dimension, of size 2, in your array `r`:

```
r = np.zeros((MeteorNum,MeteorNum,2))
```

As `XYPos[x,:] - XYPos[i,:]` in your for loop has a shape of `(2,)`

This returns a single array of shape `(5, 5, 2)`.

Comment: hmmm, no... this does work, however I end up with several arrays, whereas I only want one big array.

Comment: @user3604362 Really? `r` should be one array of shape `(5, 5, 2)`. Use `r.shape` to check.

Comment: `user`, are you confusing a 3d array with several arrays?  Do you understand the problem of trying to put 2 values into one slot of `r`?